# how to insert data in elasticsearch for nested types?

Tags: django, elasticsearch

I am new to elasticsearch.I am using elasticsearch with django.I successfully created elasticsearch index,

```
{
"productcategories": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
        "product_categories": {
            "properties": {
                "categoryName": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "subCategories": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "partNumbers": {
                            "type": "nested"
                        },
                        "subCategoryName": {
                            "type": "text"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "creation_date": "1537766526678",
            "number_of_shards": "5",
            "number_of_replicas": "1",
            "uuid": "k_8XilbrTn2jM03Djp1pXQ",
            "version": {
                "created": "6040099"
            },
            "provided_name": "productcategories"
        }
    }
}
}
```

and I am trying to insert data using format,

```
data={
        "categoryName":'TestConnector',
        "subCategories": [
            {   
                'subCategoryName':'Connector1',
                'partNumbers':['HFBR-2412T','HFBR-2506AMZ']
            },
            {   
                'subCategoryName':'Connector2',
                'partNumbers':['HFBR-2422Z','HFBR-2412Z']
            }
        ]
        }
```

settings.ES_CLIENT.index(index=ProductCategories._meta.es_index_name,doc_type=ProductCategories._meta.es_type_name,body=data)

It gives me following error,

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'object mapping for [subCategories.partNumbers] tried to parse field [null] as object, but found a concrete value')
```

can anyone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your mapping, you don't need to define `partNumbers` as `nested` since it will be a simple array of string.

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "product_categories": {
      "properties": {
        "categoryName": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "subCategories": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "partNumbers": {
              "type": "text" // use "text" instead of "nested"
            },
            "subCategoryName": {
              "type": "text"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Ref:

- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html
- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html

Comment: Thanks for sharing links.Your solution helped me.

Answer (score 0):

This error causes due to array type data you are trying to index.

You don't need to specify that a mapping is an array. You can treat any mapping as an array by using square brackets:

```
 "partNumbers": ["HFBR-2412T", "HFBR-2506AMZ"]
```

Then your mapping should be

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "product_categories": {
          "properties": {
                "categoryName": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "subCategories": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "subCategoryName": {
                            "type": "text"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```